# How to settle .NET Core show up the default main page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I settled Swagger as a default main page on my ASP.NET Core Web API. Expecting in step, Swagger appears as a default page at the moment I turn on the server.

To commit that, I added the following code line:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => 
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger v1");
                c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
            });
```

In step, I got index page didn't show up when I started the server:

[image]

I don't know what that error might be.

Here's my `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
       .AddControllers()
       .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Presentation.AssemblyReference).Assembly);

builder.Services
       .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
           c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Web", Version = "v1" }));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EnrollAppContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EnrollAppContext")));

builder.Services.AddTransient<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

var app = builder.Build();
   
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => 
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger v1");
            c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
        });
    }

    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

    app.Run();
```

I've tried to get access to API from VS Code Postman and return me the following error message:

> Error al cargar la vista web: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..

Comment: What does the picutre error mean? Shouldn't you visit 127.0.0.1:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json to see the page? And you only set swagget in development enviroment.